# Android Arrows when enter hold

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I just had discover, that when I hold press enter on android keyboard, then above the button appear two arrows - left and right. I needed to get safe code, because when I push one of them, then my focus is going down or up and my app was crashes, because event was null. Can I in some way disable this arrows when I hold enter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you say your mobile phone brand and model?